# select the 'select element item' by jQuery with help of two buttons

Tags: jquery, html, select

How to have two buttons to go up and down on a HTML select using jQuery?
I use this on up button

```
$('#selectBox option:eq(' + $("#selectt").prop("selectedIndex")-1 + '3)')
    .prop('selected', true);
```

I think we also need some 'if' to know if we reach the end of the list or no

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/VDMXe/

html

```
<input id="up" type="button" value="Up" />
<input id="down" type="button" value="down" />
<select id="chart">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

js

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#up").click(function(){
            var a = $("#chart option:selected").prev();

            if(a.length != 0)
                 a.prop("selected", "selected");
        });

        $("#down").click(function(){
            var a = $("#chart option:selected").next();

            if(a.length != 0)
                 a.prop("selected", "selected");
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<select id="foo">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<button id="up" class="dir" data-direction="-1">&uarr;</button>
<button id="down" class="dir" data-direction="1">&darr;</button>
```

Javascript

```
var sel = $('#foo');

$('.dir').on('click', function() {
    var btn = $(this),
        dir = btn.data('direction')
        currentIdx = sel.prop('selectedIndex'),
        newIdx = currentIdx + dir;
    if (newIdx < 0) newIdx = 0;
    if (newIdx >= sel[0].options.length) newIdx = sel[0].options.length - 1;
    sel.prop('selectedIndex', newIdx);
});
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/gXqKN/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#selectBox option:eq(' + $("#selectt option:selected").index()+')').prop("selected", "selected");
```